# How to prevent overflow of adjustable height tableview cell on delete

Tags: ios, uitableview

In a UITableView Controller, I have just added 'swipe to delete' by implementing `tableView: commitEditingStyle: forRowAtIndexPath`. Additionally, the rows can be selected to expand showing more content.

The undesired result after swiping:

[image]

The two lower rows remain in view after swiping until about about 0.5 seconds after the undelete animation completes.

A screenshot of IB:

[image]

The cell's contents have grown into the lower cell without it showing that it has been selected. (Selection causes the cell to increase height and give it a grayish background color.) This is occurring on every row in 2 similarly operating view controllers.

I have tried (without success) to intercept the 'selection' in several UITableViewDelegate methods, and cannot find out how to stop this from occurring. I have also tried setting the IB dynamic prototype cells to height: 85.

Looking for ideas on how to prevent this expansion from occurring.

**EDIT**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ....
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = kCellHeight;
    ....
}

#pragma mark - TableView delegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    NSInteger *rows = (NSInteger *)[sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    if (!self.rowsInSection)
        self.rowsInSection = rows;

    if (rows > 0)
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    else {
        [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [tableView setBounces:NO];
        return 1;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = self.rowsInSection > 0 ? @"numberIdentifier" : @"noNumbersIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (self.rowsInSection > 0)
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    else
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    // [self.arrayOfIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedIndexPath) {
        if (tableView.editing)
            return 85.0;
        else if (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)
            return 185.0;
    }

    return 85.0;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    if (tableView.editing)
        return nil;

    //  If real rows exist, return the path, making row selectable
    if (self.rowsInSection > 0)
        return path;

    //  Otherwise do not allow the row to be selected
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][0];

    if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] > 0)
        //  Return the contentView to stop the header from sliding with delete
        return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"numberHeaderIdentifier"].contentView;
    else
        return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"emptyHeaderIdentifier"];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 75;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Number *aNumber = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureSubviewsInCell:cell withNumber:aNumber];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are implementing the expansion in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @beyowulf. No. Editing to post two methods.

Comment: Does this always happen? Or happens on occasion?

Comment: @beyowulf  It is always happening. Since I cannot get a delegate method to run on swipe, I am looking into intercepting the gesture.

Comment: This is quite unusual. Lots of app implement both didSelectRowAtIndexPath and tableView: commitEditingStyle: forRowAtIndexPath without both firing when swiping left on a row. You should not have to intercept selection gesture. I copied your code and could implement delete and expandable rows without one triggering the other. You should post more code.

Comment: have you tried overriding prepareforreuse in cell class? That has helped me a lot when having issues with cell  retaining previous values.

Comment: @beyowulf To be clear, on the swipe, I am certain `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not firing. On swipe, the background color stays white, while on selection it turns grey. After selection, a swipe causes the background to turn white again.

Comment: You should post the code where you actually unhide or add the text that "expands" the cell or just add clipSubviews = YES on our tableViewCell

Comment: @beyowulf Updated code to *all* of tableView methods present. Trying the clipSubviews.  (I hope it is as simple as that!!)

Comment: @beyowulf  The cells are completely built when the controller is loaded. Only when a row is selected is the row height increased and the table asked to update, will some previously hidden labels be shown.

Comment: @beyowulf That `clipSubviews = YES` is interesting. (It was checked in IB) Unchecking it caused ***all*** of the content to be displayed. So, its as if the swipe gesture is overriding that (to NO) *in one cell* from the start of left swipe to one second after the end of end editing.

Comment: It seems to me that those labels are being shown at the wrong time. It's still not clear to me when they are unhidden, but it should only be when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is actually called.

Comment: @beyowulf  I agree with your last conclusion. I don't see any reason for the to appear beyond the bottom of their including cell when the row is in edit mode.

Comment: Did you override the selected setter of the table view cell? Is that what's unhiding the labels?

Comment: @beyowulf ?? I have assumed that selection causes tableView endUpdates which redraws the table with that cell's height then increased to uncover (unhide) the labels. Am I seeing this process wrong?

Comment: @beyowulf  True - not using hidden property. I don't understand what you mean by question 2. Therefore, I **am not relying** on the cells being successively higher... I don't know how this might cause the behavior.

Comment: When you swipe left on a tableviewcell the system performs some animation so it looks nice. To do this it changes the order of the views in the view hierarchy and/or turns off clip to bounds. This is done for performance reasons. So you should manage what views you would like visible yourself. One possible way is the answer below.

Comment: You should look into using auto layout and dynamically sized cells, which is how those apps achieve that behavior, if you don't want to use the hidden property of views. I've already told what is happening in your project. See the comment directly above.

Comment: @beyowulf  After more than two weeks fiddling with the 'hidden' method, I still have not solved the problem. Using the hidden views still does not keep them hidden on the swipe and I have found no way to interact with editing mode to keep them hidden. I am using auto layout and therein probably lies the issue.

Comment: You're not using UITableViewAutomaticDimension. Other than that, auto layout has nothing to do with your problem. You have views which extend beyond the bounds of your table view cell, this is normally fine, because clipSubviews is set to true, and the views that extend past their cell's frame are clipped. However, clipping subviews slows down animations. So the system turns clipSubviews off when the user swipes. Suddenly, those views that were extending into other cells show all of their content. Either hide labels that will extend into other cells or set your constraints up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the hidden property of the labels that you don't want to show when the table view cell is not selected. For example:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Number *aNumber = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:501];
    label1.text = [aNumber valueForKey:@"number"];
    if (!cell.selected)
    {
       label1.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
       label1.hidden = NO;
    }
    .....

}
```

Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:501];
    label1.text = [aNumber valueForKey:@"number"];
    label1.hidden = NO;
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

You should look into subclassing UITableViewCell so you don't have to use tags to access subviews.

Answer (score 2):

The 'hiding' solution posted by beowulf is a valid option. In addition and because the swipe (to begin editing) was causing subviews in the cell to become 'unclipped', a method needed to be overrided, like so:

```
// this method is called as the swipe to delete is started
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // only hide for unexpanded (unselected) cells
    if ([self.selectedRowIndex compare:indexPath] != NSOrderedSame)
    {
        NumberTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // a cell subclass method to hide/unhide subviews that fall into
        //  the next cell below
        [cell subViewsInCellShouldBeHidden:YES];
    }
}
```